# Do browser cached files no longer show in Firefox Developer Tools?

Tags: firefox, browser-cache, firefox-developer-tools

For me in FF 61, no cached files appear in the Network tab.

I've tested with large images where it is visually obvious if they're being transfered or coming from browser cache. They show up only when transfered  but not when coming from cache.

If I filter the Network tab with `is:cached` or `is:from-cache` I get a blank list on any website I visit.

Anyone else get this?

Comment: Cached files show up for me.  I'm using FF 61.0.1.  I suggest trying a fresh profile, and if that still fails, file a bug in bugzilla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**:

In newer versions of Firefox there's also an option `Disable Cache` directly in the `Network` tab. (*Thank you @Sebastian Zartner*)

---

**Original Answer**:

Do following:

1. Open up dev tools
2. Hit `F1` (this will opens settings panel)
3. In `Advanced settings` section (*right-bottom col*) make sure `Disable HTTP Cache (when toolbox is open)` is un-checked.
4. Hit `Ctrl+F5` and check `Network` tab again.

If above doesn't work for you, as @Tom Tromey mentioned in the comment section, first try with new profile and if doesn't work, try to report it as a bug @ [bugzilla.mozilla.org](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/)

If you don't know how to test with new profile, do following:

1. Head to `about:profiles`
2. Using `Create a New Profile`, create a new profile :p
3. Open up cmd (*on windows*) and type `firefox.exe -p myprofile -no-remote` (*replace `myprofile` with your new profile name*)

A new instance of Firefox will be opened that use your new profile, now you can use this new fox as you using Firefox.

*if firefox doesn't exist in you PATH, you need to open cmd in Firefox installation folder*

Comment: `Disable HTTP Cache (when toolbox is open)` was the crutial point and made all the difference. Cheers!

Comment: Note that in newer versions of Firefox there's also an option *Disable Cache* directly in the Network Monitor.